# Vertical slick slider is not working correctly

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I have the following problem with Slick Slider:

After the last slide, the next scroll is to the div with id 'first' (slick slider is running vertical, and with every scroll you will see a new slide). When I scroll down to the next one, the screen will go up so that the slide is visible (full screen).

It is possible to slide up, but when you slide down, it goes quickly through the slides and you end up at the div with id 'first' again.

Does anybody has a solution or is seeing the error? The code is available in JSFiddle, unfortunately it does not work the same as locally.

When removing the following code it is working correctly, only it is not possible to scroll down (to the first div).

```
if(slide == false) {
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $("#first").offset().top
  }, 800);
  slide = true;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/oa8yuf7r/4/

Comment: Just to be clear about the slides. It is possible to go from slide 1 to 2 to 3 to #first. After that it is possible to go from #first to slide 3 to slide 2 to slide 1. If you scroll down, you need to go to slide 2. Unfortunately the slider is scrolling fast to slide 2, 3 and is going to #first again..

Comment: I'm unable to comprehend what your actual issue is. Please consider editing your question.